# Prepopulate form <input> with query string parameter

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I created a contact form with two text boxes, one is email id and second is password. I want to know how make email display automatically if I include it on the url link. For example: if I enter this link "brewmeisteroilandgas.ebentechnology.com? email=donaldavalora@gmail.com" the email id included should display on the email id textbox. How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Insert in the html input element:

```
 <input name = 'email' value = '<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>'>
```

and that should work to display the email. Make sure that the link you type is:
[brewmeisteroilandgas.ebentechnology.com?email=donaldavalora@gmail.com](https://brewmeisteroilandgas.ebentechnology.com?email=donaldavalora@gmail.com)

**EDIT:** I forgot about this, and it's rather important to make it secure, so... Change it to:

```
  <input name = 'email' value = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']);?>'>
```

Comment: -1;                          this is insecure due to lack of escaping of HTML special characters. This is an XSS hole as written.

Comment: @MarkAmery thank you for you help, this work for me. I really appreciate.

Comment: Sorry about the htmlspecialchars thing